# how do I switch to a remote branch in Xcode 15

Tags: xcode, git, remote-branch

I know how to switch to a local branch in Xcode 15

but how do I change to a remote one. the dropdown list doesn't show remote branches. Typing the branch name into the filter search bar doesn't help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Remotes list in the Source Control navigator.

[image]

Those are all remote-tracking branches (i.e. `origin/album-sort-like-finder` and so on). To switch to one, use the contextual menu; the first item is Switch. Note that you will now have a detached head, as in reality it is impossible to "really" check out a remote-tracking branch.